# String or Binary Data would be truncated message during SQL Server insert command

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I'm trying to insert some data into a SQL Server table I created from scratch and cannot add the two values I would like to add which is 'Technology Question' under the column technology questions nor am I able to enter a time stamp under my time_entered column.

I'm basically trying to create a Microsoft SQL Server database to eventually take over the existence of an existing SQLite3 database so in my early test case here I am attempting to pull in one piece of data from the existing SQLite3 table into the SQL Server table.

I have tried changing the syntax around in as many ways as I can think of but am failing to get anywhere e.g. ensuring single quote tick around data values etc.

```
select * from questiontype

select [Technology Questions], time_entered
from questiontype

INSERT INTO questiontype ([Technology Questions], time_entered)
VALUES ('Technology Question', '2019-03-23 16:59')
```

I was hoping to see the data values 'Technology Question', '2019-03-23 16:59' in their respective columns within the SQL Server table 'questiontype'

When I try to do above I get the following,

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Line 6
>   String or binary data would be truncated

Comment: Post the table DDL, or run `sp_help 'questiontype'` to see the column data types and maximum lengths.  If the column's max length is too short to accommodate the data, SQL Server will give you that error.

Comment: Thanks!  That solves that problem.  Secondary issue I have is now when I run that cmd I get 'Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'int', table 'TALLY.dbo.questiontype'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.'  But I though the int column wasn't supposed to be a null

Comment: Questiontype is the table, not a column.  I thought when creating a basic table you had to create a column name such as int for integer, and set it not allow nulls so subsequent data entry into the table would auto-increment e.g. record #1, record #2, record #3 etc

Comment: Calling your column `int` is a rarely (never) a good idea. `int` is a keyword, for the data type of the same name, and calling your column that will be confusing. In your insert statement you aren't inserting a value into your column `int` and hence the error. It's quite clear here.

Comment: Yes I found I made a mistake with that.  I changed into to column name 'ID', type int and also set it as the primary key.  When I try to run the aforementioned insert statement I am still getting the 'Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'TALLY.dbo.questiontype'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.' statement

Comment: If you want an automatic incrementing **key** value you need to use the `IDENTITY` property. Remember, however, that an `IDENTITY` column does not mean that the values will be consecutive sequential values

Comment: Clearly I haven't configured this correctly then because I already have the column name 'ID' set as (Is Identity) = yes, identity increment=1 etc - Does it need to be set that way via ALTER Table ?

Comment: `ALTER`  can't be used to rename a column, how did you change its name? But very much sounds like you havent configured the column `[int]` with the `IDENTITY` property. Otherwise it's set to `NOT NULL` and does not have a default value. You either need to define a default value, give it the `IDENTITY` property or include the column in your `INSERT` (with a non-`NULL` value). Hard to tell which you need or which is the problem with out the DDL of your table, so perhaps you could add that to your question.

Comment: I do not have a column named [int] just Column Name ID with data type int.  Do you need a column name ID as well as a column name int ?  Sorry dealing with a noob here

Comment: ARGHH finally I got it!  Thanks for all of your help. Somehow I didn't commit the change to the table column properties but now I have data in my table Wheeeeee :D

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issues but had to set column name to be ID instead of 'INT' and had to make sure it held the identity property.  Also had to increase the character limitation for each column.